# Make hard links from all subfolders to all subfolders in Linux?

Tags: bash, tree, cp

I have two folders, let's call them A and B. Both folders have a folder structure under them, that is identical. Say A has folders 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. B has folders 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. All of the subfolders of A have various files in them (e.g /A/1/file.txt   /A/2/anotherfile.txt.). Same goes for subfolders of the subfolders, so the tree is quite deep.

Now, can I make hard links in all B:s folders and subfolders? So that both tree structures look the same and all folders and subfolders have the same files in them. Well, hard links that is.

*cp -l all files in A into B*

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` 4, you could write a simple loop like

```
cd A
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/; do
    mkdir -p "B/$d"
    for f in "$d"; do
        [[ -f $f ]] && cp -l "$f" "B/$f"
    done
done
```

Comment: Even though my solution is brief and elegant, the way `--link-dest` is confusingly explained in the man page makes it a headache to use so I'd probably rather use a loop myself unless I remember how to use `rsync` for this scenario off the top of my head, so have an upvote.

Comment: I was going to add an `rsync` answer as well, but I was similarly confused about whether it would work :)

Comment: I admit I did have to play around for a few minutes, I never remember how `--link-dest` works but it certainly is handy :)

Comment: I like this solution since it allows to create additional conditions for creating links - rsync would not work. Upvoted :-)

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using `rsync`:

```
$ rsync -a --link-dest=../A A/ B
```

Example:

```
# Optionally, get rid of your destination
$ rm -rf B

$ find
.
./A
./A/2
./A/2/foo
./A/1
./A/1/foo

# If the argument to --link-dest is relative, it is relative
# to the target directory which is B in this case, hence the ../A
$ rsync -a --link-dest=../A A/ B

$ find
.
./B
./B/2
./B/2/foo
./B/1
./B/1/foo
./A
./A/2
./A/2/foo
./A/1
./A/1/foo

# Notice the identical inodes
$ ls -1i {A,B}/{1,2}/foo
349408 A/1/foo
349409 A/2/foo
349408 B/1/foo
349409 B/2/foo
```

Comment: How about cp -al A/* B/

Comment: That, uh, seems to work. D'oh. Note that this is not portable though, but in your case it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: What does "not portable" mean in this case?

Comment: That `-a` and `-l` are not POSIX so you cannot rely on a `cp` implementation having those...but neither can you rely on having `rsync` available so it doesn't really matter...I just felt it should be mentioned. For example, Apple's `cp` (`darwin`) doesn't seem to come with `-l` according to the [`man` page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html).